# How to set error endicon in TextInputLayout.that show when error occur and disappear when there is no error

Tags: java, android

I want to set error endicon in TextinputLayout that show when error occur. What should I do?

```
Emailtext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(charSequence.length()<5)
                {
                  EmailLayout.setError("Error is occur");
                  EmailLayout.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_info_black_48);
                  EmailLayout.setEndIconActivated(true);
                  EmailLayout.setEndIconContentDescription("Error icon");

                }
                else
                {

                    EmailLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What kind of error check?

Answer (score 0):

In your else condition,

```
EmailLayout.setError(null);
```